# Change button image in Unity 3D

Tags: image, button, unity-game-engine

I'm a Unity nob, so please don't flame me for this question.

I'm trying to change a simple UI button to look like a Play button (via simple Play PNG image), I see that the Button have a `Source Image` under the Image script, but as far as I can see I must select a Sprite.

How can I create a Sprite from a PNG Image?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Unity's sprite is a kind of Texture.

1. Import your PNG by drag your file to the Project panel, Unity will automatically generate texture for you.
2. Click on that file, The Inspector panel will show texture's Import setting.
   [image]
3. In Inspector, Choose texture type as **Sprite (2D and UI)**, Hit Apply at the bottom.
   [image]
4. In Project Panel, Drag this texture to your **Source Image** under **Image Script**

Comment: Thanks bro! So simple if you know that to do